# Run OpenCover, Gallio, MbUnit under Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo, mbunit, gallio, opencover

I have a C# project that I have used OpenCover and Gallio to run the MbUnit UnitTests from Nant script.  I'm trying to set this up in Bamboo.  I see Bamboo has NUnit runner, but doesn't seem to have anything for MbUnit.

Any idea how one would run the MbUnit UnitTests from Bamboo ?

Answer (score 0):

Most CI systems have the ability to execute generic tasks (for this type of scenario)

A quick peruse of the site shows that the Console (Builder) Task would be the one; or you could also get it working in a nant script and then use that.

You would then use OpenCover to run NUnit or MbUnit runners as required.

Comment: After playing with this myself - I found the script task much more useful to trigger my nant scripts via the batch file I already use on the desktop.